# How to prove $\min(\delta a_k)\le\delta S\le \max(\delta a_k)$?

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods

We have sum of exact numbers: $$S=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n$$
And sum of their corresponding approximate numbers:

$$S_0=a_{0_1}+a_{0_2}+a_{0_3}+\cdots +a_{0_n}$$
Our lecturer wrote the following inequality without any proof: $$\min(\delta a_k)\le\delta S\le \max(\delta a_k)$$

Where $\delta_{a_k}$ is relative error of $a_k$.

I am very curious to know why this inequality works.

I know $\delta S=\cfrac{\Delta a_1}{|S|}+\cfrac{\Delta a_2}{|S|}+\cfrac{\Delta a_3}{|S|}+\cdots+\cfrac{\Delta a_n}{|S|}\quad\quad,\quad \delta a_k=\cfrac{\Delta a_k}{|a_k|}$ If I'm not mistaking

Therefor :
$$\min(\cfrac{\Delta a_k}{|a_k|})\le\ \cfrac{\Delta a_1}{|S|}+\cfrac{\Delta a_2}{|S|}+\cfrac{\Delta a_3}{|S|}+\cdots+\cfrac{\Delta a_n}{|S|}\le \max(\cfrac{\Delta a_k}{|a_k|})$$
But no idea comes to my mind how to prove this inequality works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, denote $m=\min \left(\frac{\Delta a_k}{|a_k|}\right)$ and $M=\max \left(\frac{\Delta a_k}{|a_k|}\right).$
Then for each $k$ $$m \cdot|a_k|\le \frac{\Delta a_k}{|a_k|}|a_k|\le M\cdot {|a_k|} \tag 1$$
Rewrite
$$\ \cfrac{\Delta a_1}{|S|}+\cfrac{\Delta a_2}{|S|}+\cfrac{\Delta a_3}{|S|}+\cdots+\cfrac{\Delta a_n}{|S|}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{|S|}\left(\frac{\Delta a_1}{|a_1|}|a_1|+\dots +\frac{\Delta a_n}{|a_n|}|a_n|\right)}.$$

With the use of $(1)$ we get
$$\frac{1}{|S|}\left(m|a_1|+\dots + m|a_n|\right)\le \color{blue}{\frac{1}{|S|}\left(\frac{\Delta a_1}{|a_1|}|a_1|+\dots +\frac{\Delta a_n}{|a_n|}|a_n|\right)}\le \frac{1}{|S|}\left(M|a_1|+\dots + M|a_n|\right)$$
Left inequality (that you want to prove) is true as $|S|\le|a_1|+\dots + |a_n|,$ the right one holds provided $a_k$ have equal signs.

Comment: I don't understand last why last inequality works. and how it prove $\min(\delta a_k)\le\delta S\le \max(\delta a_k)$ ?

Comment: @soheil Looks like the last inequality is a direct consequence of $(1)$.

Comment: @Surb I got it. but I don't understand how we prove $\min(\delta a_k)\le\delta S\le \max(\delta a_k)$ from last inequality

Comment: @soheil The blue part in the last inequality is equal to $\delta S$ as shown by the equation above, and if $a_1,\ldots,a_n\geq 0$, then $|S| = |a_1|+\ldots+|a_n|$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you !